# Is below code vulnerable to cross site scripting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, xss

I have below method which I have called in many files in my webform project.

```
public static void MsgBox(String ex, Page pg, Object obj)
        {
            string s = "<SCRIPT language='javascript'>alert('" + ex.Replace("\r\n", "\\n").Replace("'", "") + "'); </SCRIPT>";
            Type cstype = obj.GetType();
            ClientScriptManager cs = pg.ClientScript;
            cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, s, s.ToString());
        }
```

In one of my .cs file I have called this method:

```
_obj.insertrecordbysp("hac_UpdateUserPassword", _spr);

                    int returnva = Convert.ToInt32(_spr[2].Value.ToString());
                    if (returnva.Equals(1))
                    {
                        SqlData.MsgBox("'" + txtUserID.Text.Trim() + "' User Login ID Password Reset Sucessfully", this.Page, this);
                        SqlData.history(Session["ad_mobileno"].ToString(), Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"], "Success", "Land on button click Update User Password Page", "UpdateUserPassword Page", Session["ad_name"].ToString());
                        txtUserID.Text = "";                    
                    }
```

Is this code is vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting, if yes, then how can I resolve the same ?

Thanks.

Comment: "Is this code is vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting" - yes

Comment: "if yes, then how can I resolve the same?" - with difficulty

Comment: Dai- can you please explain me how it is vulnerable?

Comment: You aren't escaping JS strings correctly (you're only escaping single-quoted strings, not double-quoted strings - nor other types of escapes in JS (e.g. backslash-escaped).). Instead of (incorrectly) doing it by yourself you should use `System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder`. **And no-one should be using WebForms in 2022**.

Comment: I think it is not vulnerable to Cross Site scripting, As per your code looks like you are showing this message to the same customer after he is resetting his password.
Only thing you have to make sure is that txtUserID should be system generated id on your backed, so that any user cannot entered something which can execute on browser.

If txtUserId is always a number then i think no need to worry.

Comment: @mksmanjit That is incorrect: `txtUserID.Text` is a `WebControls.TextBox` that  contains unsanitized user input which is passed _almost verbatim_ to the ClientScriptManager, and so is a vulnerability-point for XSS.

Comment: Dai- oh ok, I thought this is userId field which is passed from backend.